# python-shell node, keep a python script running

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, stdin

Would anyone know when using python-shell if you can keep the python script running when its called from Javascript? Maybe call a method from a Python class from Javascript using python-shell?

For example this code works but it kills the Python script every time its called.

```
let {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");

let options = {
  mode: "text",
  args: ["read", "12345:2", "analogInput", "2"],
};

PythonShell.run("bac0Worker.py", options, function (err, results) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err)
    console.log("An error happened")
  }else{
      // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
    console.log("results: ", results);
    console.log("Python Script Finished");
    }
})
```

On the Python side I am experimenting with a package called BAC0 for BACnet systems. What I am trying to do is figure out if I can keep the BAC0 script running, I think under the hood of BAC0 there's alot of process going on where it may create lots of unnecessary traffic on a BACnet network if the script is started/stopped a lot.

bac0Worker.py

```
import sys
import BAC0

BAC0.log_level('silence')
bacnet = BAC0.lite()


def do_things(address,object_type,object_instance):
        try:
            read_vals = f'{address} {object_type} {object_instance} presentValue'
            read_result = bacnet.read(read_vals)
            if isinstance(read_result, str):
                pass
            else:
                read_result = round(read_result,2)
            print(read_result)
        except Exception as error:
            print("read error")


def main():
    # args from Javascript
    first = sys.argv[1]
    second = sys.argv[2]
    third = sys.argv[3]
    fourth = sys.argv[4]

    # get sensor data
    do_things(second, third, fourth)

    # all done    
    bacnet.disconnect()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("bacnet app error")
        bacnet.disconnect()
```

Like I mentioned the code works if I run from Node I can see the sensor value from the BACnet network 71.7 degrees.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\start.js
results:  (1) ['71.7']
Python Script Finished
```

Hopefully this makes sense, sorry for the odd question but curious if anyone would have any tips for how to keep the Python script running where I could then just pass values (sensor & device addressing info) to BAC0 script to request a BACnet read from the network. In the main function of the Python file if I replace this:

```
# all done    
bacnet.disconnect()
```

With:

```
while True:
    pass
```

This would keep the Python file alive I just don't know how to pass values to a live Python script using python-shell. Thanks for any tips not a lot of wisdom here best practices. Curious if I should change my `do_things` function into a Python class with a method called `do_things` where then this class could get called from Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.js

```
const { PythonShell } = require("python-shell");
let pyshell = new PythonShell("my_script.py");
pyshell.send("hello");
pyshell.on("message", function (message) {
  console.log(message);
});
setTimeout(() => {
  pyshell.send("Another Hello");
}, 3000);
const end = () => {
  pyshell.end(function (err, code, signal) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("finished");
  });
};
// end();
```

.py

```
import sys
    
def log():  
    print('hello from python')
while True:
    inp = input(" ")
    if inp=="hello":
        log()
```

this will keep the process running unless you call the `end` method from the nodejs or some error occurs. This may incur performance issues because python thingy will be sharing same resources as your nodejs. A better way to do this would be to use a microservice like deploy some Rest Api which handles python specific tasks.

Comment: What does `setTimeout(() => {
  pyshell.send("Another Hello");
}, 10);` do?

Comment: Could you give me one more tip? How can I modify the `pyshell.send("Another Hello");` on a reoccurring interval? For example every 60 seconds `pyshell.send("Another Hello");`

Comment: `setTimeout(() => {   pyshell.send("Another Hello"); }, timeInMilliSeconds);` is just for demo purpose...if your want to run something continuously then replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval`. More about setInterval here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: Basically the syntax is `setInterval( functionYouWantToRun , timeInMilliseconds )`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun Ill post what I was able to learn from @sandeep (thanks a million btw), this works. I can print BACnet sensor values which are gathered from Python from running a javascript file on 60 second `setInterval(pythonDo, 60000);` with keeping the Python file alive:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\start.js
BAC0 start success
 68.47
 68.43
 68.29
 68.25
```

***start.js***

```
const { PythonShell } = require("python-shell");

let pyshell = new PythonShell("bac0Worker.py");

function pythonDo() {
  pyshell.send("read 12345:2 analogInput 2"); 
}

pyshell.on("message", function (message) {
  console.log(message);
});

var data = setInterval(pythonDo, 60000);
```

***bac0Worker.py***

```
import sys
import BAC0

BAC0.log_level('silence')
bacnet = BAC0.lite()
print("BAC0 start success")

# available BACnet actions
SUBSTRING_READ = "read"
SUBSTRING_WRITE = "write"
SUBSTRING_RELEASE = "release"


def bac0_worker(action, BACnet_request, **kwargs):
    value = kwargs.get('value', None)
    priority = kwargs.get('priority', None)

    if action == "read":
        try:
            read_vals = f'{BACnet_request} presentValue'
            read_result = bacnet.read(read_vals)
            if isinstance(read_result, str):
                pass
            else:
                read_result = round(read_result,2)
            print(read_result)
        except Exception as error:
            print("read error")
  
    elif action == "write":
        try:
            write_vals = f'{BACnet_request} presentValue {value} - {priority}'
            bacnet.write(write_vals)
            print(write_vals)         
        except Exception as error:
            print("write error")

    elif action == "release":
        try:    
            release_vals = f'{BACnet_request} presentValue null - {priority}'
            bacnet.write(release_vals)
            print(release_vals)
        except Exception as error:
            print("release error")
    else:
        return "server error on BACnet opts"


def main():
        while True:
            # from javascript
            inp = input(" ")

            for word in inp.split():
                if SUBSTRING_READ == word:
                    stripped_string = inp.replace(SUBSTRING_READ + " ", "")
                    # do a BACnet READ request with BAC0
                    bac0_worker(SUBSTRING_READ,stripped_string)

                if SUBSTRING_WRITE == word:
                    print("WRITE Match Found")

                if SUBSTRING_RELEASE == word:
                    print("RELEASE Match Found")                    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("bacnet app error")
        bacnet.disconnect()
```

Comment: Interesting work guys henry, @sandeep.kgp